# How do you use match_args and kw_args together in a dataclass?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

Given the following example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str = ""


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class AnotherPerson:
    name: str = ""


print(Person.__match_args__)
print(AnotherPerson.__match_args__)
```

When running, you get the following:

```
('name',)
()
```

According to the documentation for the [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) `match_args` argument (emphasis mine):

> match_args: If true (the default is True), ***the __match_args__ tuple will be created from the list of parameters to the generated __init__() method*** (even if __init__() is not generated, see above). If false, or if __match_args__ is already defined in the class, then __match_args__ will not be generated.

Given that `match_args` defaults to true, I would think that the `__match_args__` variable should be set to the values as they appear in the `__init__` method, though this does not appear to be the case with keyword arguments. Is this just an undocumented restriction, or am I doing something wrong?

Regardless, how would I go about generating these `__match_args__` tuples without explicitly writing them out?

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I stumbled on it so I figured I'd answer (tested in python 3.12), in case other people stumble on it too.

First, I suspect the reason the `__match_args__` doesn't include keyword only arguments is because you can already use keywords in the match case, and it's a bit odd to make the parameters keyword only in the class, but not in the match (see below). So if you need the class to be keyword only and the following works for you, it might be the best answer:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass(kw_only=True)
class A:
    a: int
    b: int

a = A(a=1, b=2)
match a:
    case A(a=1, b=_):
        print('Of type A with .a=1')
```

But if that's not sufficient, you can modify the `__match_args__` attribute programmatically by using `dataclasses.fields`. If you're gonna do this a lot, you could make a decorator that does it for you - but you'll have to decide how to handle keyword only mixed with non keyword only and inheritance (as applicable). For example:

```
def add_keyword_match_args(cls):
    # dataclasses.fields gives a tuple of objects
    # representing each field - we are interested
    # in the string name of the field and whether
    # or not it's keyword only. We can add these
    # to the end of __match_args__
    cls.__match_args__ += tuple(
        field.name
        for field in dataclasses.fields(cls)
        if field.kw_only
    )
    return cls

@add_keyword_match_args
@dataclasses.dataclass(kw_only=True)
class A:
    a: int = 3
    b: int = 4

@add_keyword_match_args
@dataclasses.dataclass
class B(A):
    c: int
    d: int

print(A.__match_args__)  # ('a', 'b')
print(B.__match_args__)  # ('c', 'd', 'a', 'b')

b = B(1, 2)
match b:
    case B(1, 2):
        print('Yay.')

match b:
    case B(1, 2, 3, 4):
        print('Yay.')

match b:
    case B(1, 2, a=3, b=4):
        print('Yay.')
```

Note in the exact example I gave above, the keyword only arguments of `A` are in the tuple for `B` after the positional `c` and `d`. Generally speaking, dataclass stuff puts the fields in orders so that the base class's fields come before the child class's fields - but if we did that so that `B.__match_args__ == ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')` then `B(1, 2)` would not match against `B(1, 2)`, which seems like it'd be confusing.

Of course, the fact that we can do `B(1, 2, 3, 4)` in the match case, but not to create an object might also a bit confusing. As is the fact that for the match case, the base class's fields are after the child class's, even though in every other situation this is not true. I think this is unavoidable removing the keyword only nature of `A.a` and `A.b` for the match case only.

So again, I'd probably suggest just matching using keyword arguments in the match case if possible in whatever situation came up. But if you need to modify `__match_args__` programmatically, then it is possible.